# Logistic Regression accuracy degrades with added features

Tags: regression, logistic, loss-functions

I have a logistic model.  As I add features, my accuracy degrades, even on the training set.  I would imagine, since I am using cross-entropy loss, that adding even irrelevant features should improve the accuracy of the model, since it acts to drive the predicted probability of the true class higher.

How is it that this can happen?

Comment: How are yoy making class assignments to compute accuraccy? Logistic regression only produces probabilities.

Comment: Logistic model predictions return a vector of probabilities that sum to 1.  We make a class assignment with a simple $argmax$

Comment: Accuracy and cross-entropy don't measure the same thing. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_paradox

Comment: Upon further inspection, the cross entropy loss has also increased!  I will post this in a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be experiencing something called "Stein's Paradox" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stein%27s_example

What it says that if you add random noise to your data, there will exist an estimator that uniformly performs better than estimation without the noise. However, what it does not say is that if you have an estimator, (in the case of logistic regression probably something computed using IRLS) then that estimator will be improved by adding noise, just that somewhere out there, there will exist an estimator that does better using that noise.

Comment: Obviously for least-squares the loss function is not identical to accuracy, so descreasing my loss will not be guaranteed to incrase my accuracy.  However, for cross-entropy loss, the loss boils down to the log of the probability for the true label predicted by my model.  When I add a feature with coefficient $\alpha$, this should not go down, since we can set $\alpha$ to 0 to obtain the previous model.  Thus the probability of the true label must go up.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by adding a feature with coefficient $\alpha$ could you be more explicit?

Comment: Sure.  Logistic regression is given as $P(y=1|\theta) = \frac{1}{1+\exp(\theta^T*x)}$ where $\theta$ is some vector of feature coefficients.  By adding a feature with coefficient $\alpha$ I mean that we add a feature into our vector $x$, and the corresponding coefficient in $\theta$ is given as $\alpha$

Comment: I'm actually doing multinomial regression, so there are mutliple coefficients, but the analogy holds.